# -webkit-box-sizing property doesn't show up in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, css, webkit

I have "Box Model Hack" issue. I found out that in all browsers except Google Chrome. So I searched the solutions and saw that I should put `-webkit-box-sizing` property in CSS and define it  as `content-box`

I installed CSS3 for VS2010 and restart it, then CSS 3.0 showed up in drop down list on style sheet tool bar in VS2010. I saw new properties coming from CSS3 but I cannot find `-webkit-box-sizing`

Should I need VS2010 SP1? or is there something missing? Besides, if there is another Box Model Hack solution for Chrome, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

All `-webkit` properties are specific to browsers running on the [Web Kit Browser Engine](http://www.webkit.org/) and are not part of the official CSS3 specification.

You can simply type in the CSS you require either in your stylesheet or your CSS style code block. I dont think VS will include a menu item for it (and many other proprietry CSS properties).

Having said that, I've just found a [CSS 3 Intellisense Schema](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7211bcac-091b-4a32-be2d-e797be0db210) that includes the items you're wanting.

Comment: VS includes other -webkit properties as menu items like -webkit-box-shadow. I tried just to type in the CSS as you said, but it didn't work. I think it should show up as a menu item.

Comment: I already installed CSS 3 Intellisense Schema as I said above.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"? Most people write their CSS by hand.

Comment: I mean typing -webkit-box-sizing:content-box; didn't fix Box Model Hack issue. Boxes didn't fit into div properly. Because VS doesn't include that CSS property.

Comment: Does it work in your browser though? Is your concern with the design view in VS? Does it really matter what VS includes?

Comment: For this issue it is not really, but in the future it might be for comfortable coding. If it had worked in my browser, I wouldn't have asked for help. I tried that -webkit in all code blocks in my stylesheet. I also added box-sizing property. Nothing changed.

Comment: What browser are you testing in? As far as I know, Safari is the only major browser using the webkit engine.

Comment: I tested the page in every major browsers. Only Chrome made problem. Chrome also uses the webkit engine.